# scala - how to explode JSON array similar to DataFrame with json4s?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, json4s

My initial approach to processing JSON from two different API endpoints containing Store info and Sales info was to: concatenate each store's JValue(struct) with the corresponding sales JValue(containing an array of sales). Then I created a DataFrame and exploded Sales array to be able to select data from it later.

```
 val salesDf: DataFrame = salesRawDf.select($"stores", explode($"sales").as("sl"))
          .select($"stores.id", $"stores.name", $"sl.id", $"sl.current_sales", $"sl.review")
```

But now it seems that the explode causes a huge overhead and I'm getting `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` when running a Spark job.

So I decided to modify the logic and parse sales in place where I was concatenating JValues, before the parallel execution.

What would be the analogue of `exploding` sales array as above when parsing JSON with json4s? Now I'm concatenating stores and sales this way:

```
  def mergeSales(storeJValue: JValue): String = {
    val salesJValue: JValue = parse(rawJson)

    val store = compact(render(storeJValue))
    val sales = compact(render(salesJValue))
    val mergedSales: String = s"""{"store":$store,"sales":$sales}"""

    mergedSales
  }
```